# Elemento da Lista Android

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma lista de sons, queria pegar cada elemento da lista e emitir o som que está gravado no banco. Exemplo: ao clicar em um elemento que está na lista, emitisse o som gravado que está no banco de dados, já tenho tudo gravado, só queria saber como eu faço para ao clicar emitir o som.

```js
public static final String KEY_SOM = "NomeSom";

String Som = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabSom3 ( `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "`NomeSom` TEXT, " +
                "`ArqSom` TEXT);";  

public void CarregaDadoSom(){
    MostraDados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstSom);

    if(VerificaRegistroSom()){
        String [] Coluna = new String [] {KEY_SOM};;

        AdapterLista = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lista_som, cursor, Coluna, new int[] {R.id.txtsom});

        MostraDados.setAdapter(AdapterLista);
    }else {
        MensagemAlerta("Erro Banco de Dados", "Você não possui nenhum cadastro!");
    }
   
}

private boolean VerificaRegistroSom() {
    try {
        BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
        cursor = BancoDados.rawQuery("Select * from tabSom3", null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) { //procurar registro no banco
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch(Exception erro){
        MensagemAlerta("Erro Banco de Dados", "Não foi possivel VERIFICAR dados " + erro);
        return false;
    } finally {
        BancoDados.close();
    }
}

public void play(View view) {
    try{
        myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
        myPlayer.prepare();
        myPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopPlay(View view){
    try {
        if (myPlayer != null) {
            myPlayer.stop();
            myPlayer.release();
            myPlayer = null;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

`.xml`:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/txtsom"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Somente em minha lista aparece o nome do som, mas eu queria que emitisse o som gravado.

Comment: Que tipo de dado o som está sendo gravado no banco?

Comment: editei o código, ele pega o caminho do som

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `KEY_SOM`?

Comment: editei no codigo

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, 
O Código é meio grande, então criei no gist: https://gist.github.com/Domacoski/5d067ecfaf4e091233bf 
É um Fragment que exibe uma lista de todos os mp3.
Clicando sobre o item, ele executa o arquivo.
Espero ter ajudado! 
Saudações,

Comment: No caso o meu esta no SDCARD e esta em uma lista (ListView)

Comment: @GabrielSantanaBonatto, alterei a resposta! de uma olhada, e qualquer dúvida, pergunte! Saudações,

Comment: pode me ajudar no chat? quero tirar umas duvidas

Comment: Posso sim ! ! !

Comment: tem como vc criar um chat, n estou conseguindo, muito complicado criar um hehe, procurei no google mas n consegui

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25629/discussion-between-gabriel-santana-bonatto-and-thiago-luiz-domacoski).